# Stored procedure with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I need to execute my stored procedure but I don't know how to do it I have my project with my folders which are routes, models, public, controller.
I have 2 tables which are related by the id and at the time of making a record both should be affected.
I will leave my stored procedure so you can see how I have it in my database:

```
    delimiter //
`create procedure sp_agregarAlumno`
`(p_nombre varchar(100),p_sexo char,p_telefono varchar(20),p_email varchar(100),`
`p_clave  varchar(20),p_noControl varchar(8),p_anioEgreso int,p_promedio float,`
`p_idCarrera int,out msg varchar(500))` 
`begin`

`declare idUsuario int;`

`declare continue handler for SQLException`
begin
    set msg='Error: No se puede registrar al usuario, intente mas tarde.';
    rollback;
end;
select registrarUsuario(p_nombre,p_sexo,p_telefono,p_email,p_clave,'E') into idUsuario;
if idUsuario!=0 then
    start transaction;
    insert into alumnos values(p_noControl,p_anioEgreso,p_promedio,idUsuario,p_idCarrera);
    commit;
    set msg='Usuario creado con exito.';
else
    set msg='Error:El email del usuario que desea agregar ya existe, favor de elegir otro';
end if;    
end;//
delimiter ;
```

but I need to run it in the project and I don't know, how to do it?

Comment: Hmm. What stops you from calling `sequelize.query('call sp_agregarAlumno($nombe, <other parameters>)', { bind: { nombe, <other arguments> }})`?

Comment: ok but why use in the parameter nombre as $nombre.
I am using postman for testing and I need to send all the parameters, also do I have to have the model of the 2 tables or do I not need it to call the stored procedure?, and thanks for answering my question

Comment: Indicating parameters with `$` refers to arguments with the same names (w/o $) you will pass in `bind` option. So $nombre will take a value from `nombre` prop of `bind` option. And what's going on inside a stored procedure is its own business no matter how many tables you will use in it. Just call it properly indicating all required parameters

Comment: And how can I send the parameters from postman, since I have seen videos and they assign values ​​to each parameter to perform the tests and I need to do it but from postman I don't know if I can put the code of how it would be please

Comment: I see. You firstly need to learn about Express.js, how to create a simple service with a simple route in which you will be able to call your stored procedure using Sequelize (of course, you will need to learn how to configure Sequelize too).

Comment: That way you will be able to make a request to this route from Postman. You said you already have routes, controllers and so on. So what's the point?

Comment: It was just how to execute the procedure and I know that with the route it is executed in postman, I wanted to know how to pass the parameters of the stored procedure as well as I wrote it but I have seen videos that the parameters are assigned the static values

Comment: I just wanted to know how to use the code without assigning values ​​and in postman I assign them